# BigQuery: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed. Error: 7367027

Tags: google-bigquery

Trying to run a simple delete statement and the command simply times out and throws the error in the title.

If I change the where to operate on a subset of the data, it works and then I was able to run the where true version successfully. I can't wrap my head around why I'm getting this error.

I've tried running this from the python library as well as from the console, with both returning the same error. I've also tried deleting the table entirely and then recreating it, which did nothing.

```sql
delete from `<table>` 
where true
```

Comment: Please file a bug instead. See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/support#file-feature-requests-and-bug-reports

Comment: Did that as well. Thanks!